# How to install an older "jquery-rails" gem version that I want ? --- $(...).live() not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Until now, I've been relying upon the default rails 4 jQuery gem for all my jQuery needs `gem 'jquery-rails'`. However, for a new enhancement to my app I wanted to use jQuery `.live()` function but seems that's only available 1.3~. Should I just manually install the version of jQuery I want rather than include it as a gem? What's the best way to specify which jQuery version I want?

Answer (score 4):

The `.live()` method is **deprecated** as of jQuery 1.7+

### Solution:

See [VERSION.md](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/VERSIONS.md) to see which versions of jquery-rails bundle which versions of jQuery.
For instance you could use any `jquery-rails` gem prior to version 1.0.17 and everything will work fine. For example:

```ruby
gem 'jquery-rails', '1.0.16'  # This match the jQuery version 1.6.4
```

That said, you should use **always** the latest version of jQuery because every iteration provides a lot of bugfixes and better cross-browser compatibility. See below how to handle this.

### Further reading:

As of jQuery 1.7+ you should use `.on()` to atach event handlers. The documentation even recommends for older version of jQuery the use of `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`

Use of the `.live()` method is no longer recommended since later versions of jQuery offer better methods that do not have its drawbacks.

Rewriting the `.live()` method in terms of its successors is straightforward; these are templates for equivalent calls for all three event attachment methods:

```javascript
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler ); // jQuery 1.3+
$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler ); // jQuery 1.4.3+
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler ); // jQuery 1.7+
```

If you want to improve your knowledge about the subject please, continue reading the official documentation of the *old* [.live()](https://api.jquery.com/live/) method and the *new* [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

**A conversion example:**

The following three method calls are functionally equivalent:

```javascript
$( "a.offsite" ).live( "click", function() {
  alert( "Goodbye!" ); // jQuery 1.3+
});
$( document ).delegate( "a.offsite", "click", function() {
  alert( "Goodbye!" ); // jQuery 1.4.3+
});
$( document ).on( "click", "a.offsite", function() {
  alert( "Goodbye!" ); // jQuery 1.7+
});
```

Comment: Using on(), if I update the HTML in the DOM does it re-assign the events I assigned on the first page load automatically (like live() seems to do)? Or should I write a line of code to do this after HTML is updated in the DOM? I couldn't see if this was the case in the documentation.

Comment: I'm almost sure that it does since the behavior are pretty the same. However read the .on() doc updated in the post and see if it works. If you want, create a jsfiddle to hack on it. Let me know if you have luck.